# Azure - Cannot delete Network Security Group

Tags: azure, bad-request, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to run the following command to delete an unused Network Security Group in Azure but the command keeps returning "BadRequest"??

```
> PS C:\> Remove-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
> -ResourceGroupName xxxxx-group -Name xxxxxxx-nsg -Force
> 
> Remove-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup : Operation returned an invalid
> status code 'BadRequest' StatusCode: 400 ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
> OperationID : 'dd6a9c5f-2713-438b-8b4f-a0916db7e78b' At line:1 char:1
> + Remove-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName xxxx-test-gr ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup], NetworkCloudException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.RemoveAzureNetworkSecurityGroupCommand
```

Comment: i suggest you do the same command with the `-debug` switch and either figure out the problem or post the error output here so we can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your NSG was associated with some network interfaces or subnet. We can check it via Azure Portal or PowerShell.
Via **Azure Portal**, **Resourcegroup->NSG->overview->Associated with**:
[image]

Via **PowerShell**:
We can use this command `Get-AzureRmEffectiveNetworkSecurityGroup` to **list NSG associated information**:

```
PS C:\Users> Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName vm | format-table name

Name
----
jasonvm815
PS C:\Users> Get-AzureRmEffectiveNetworkSecurityGroup -NetworkInterfaceName jasonvm815 -ResourceGroupName vm


NetworkSecurityGroup   : {
                           "Id": "/subscriptions/xxxx7abb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0361e29axxx/resourceGroups/vm/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/jasonvm-nsg"
                         }
Association            : {
                           "NetworkInterface": {
                             "Id": "/subscriptions/xxxx7abb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0361e29axxxx/resourceGroups/vm/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/jasonvm815"
                           }
                         }
EffectiveSecurityRules : [
                           {
                             "Name": "securityRules/default-allow-ssh",
                             "Protocol": "Tcp",
                             "SourcePortRange": "0-65535",
                             "DestinationPortRange": "22-22",
                             "SourceAddressPrefix": "0.0.0.0/0",
                             "DestinationAddressPrefix": "0.0.0.0/0",
                             "ExpandedSourceAddressPrefix": [],
                             "ExpandedDestinationAddressPrefix": [],
                             "Access": "Allow",
```

Use PowerShell to **dissociated an NSG from a NIC**, we can follow those steps:

```
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName RG-NSG -Name TestNICWeb1
$nic.NetworkSecurityGroup = $null
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
```

Use PowerShell to **dissociated an NSG from a subnet**, we can follow those steps:

```
$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName RG-NSG -Name TestVNet
$subnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $vnet -Name FrontEnd
$subnet.NetworkSecurityGroup = $null
Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -VirtualNetwork $vnet
```

After that, we can use command `Remove-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup` to delete Azure NSG.
More information about powershell to manage NSG, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-ps).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.